# Saving all generated images

Tags: texturing, interface, image, baking

Is there any way to save all **generated** images to the specific folder while keeping a corect link to Image Texture node in associated material?

The situation is: I've created several materials and textures (UV node - Image Texture node - Principled BSDF) for my high to low poly baking, but didn't save texture blanks to anywhere. So, if the file will be closed, all data is going to be lost? Or there's a way to somehow batch saving those baked images and keep linked materials to know where to find them?